# OnClick() on images adds the same fragment with different information

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclick

What I want to do is to create an app where I have clickable images in the main screen.

The idea I had in mind is when I click an image a Fragment with a WebView appears. And every image has to give me different information in that WebView but I couldn't do it so I went on with this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;
    private ImageView image3;
    private ImageView image4;
    private ImageView image5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = null;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView1:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity1.class);
        break;
        case R.id.imageView2:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity2.class);
        break;
        case R.id.imageView3:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity3.class);
        break;
        case R.id.imageView4:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity4.class);
        break;
        case R.id.imageView5:
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebviewActivity5.class);
        break;
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to work with Fragments so I just created different activities which call the xml with a WebView and I changed the WebView's content in each activity programmatically.

I believe there is a shorter and simpler way using Fragments. Could anyone guide me through it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resuming you want to show the same fragment, or activity, with the same layout and webview BUT with different contents inside this webview. So pass parameters to this second activity, or fragment. There you collect those parameters and act as you want in each case (load content X or Y on your webview).

These parameters can be passed with the help of sharedpreferences or bundle arguments.

EDIT: if you want to make things easier, do not use fragments at this time. If and when you will need to implement a ViewPager, for example, to swipe your screens, then it will be another time. For now, let's expand your activities sample and make things happen.

First of all, in your **AndroidManifest.xml** you have to get permission to access the internet (if you plan to load webpages from there), so put this before the `<application>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And then, inside `<application>`, declare the second activity, where you will show your webview. Let's call this activity Webview.class. Define it this way, yet inside your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".Webview" android:label="My Test Webview" />
```

Now let's see the whole **Webview.java**:

```
public class Webview extends Activity{

private WebView wv;
private String url;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    // get the url to open
    Intent intentBundle = this.getIntent();
    url = intentBundle.getStringExtra("url");

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // needed to open url inside our webview, otherwise it will open at the default browser
    wv.loadUrl(url);
}}
```

Fine. This java will need the layout file I called **webview.xml**, with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff0000"
>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, at the onClick of your **MainActivity.java**, change the places where you're calling your auxiliar activities like this:

1 - From this `Intent i = null;` to this `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Webview.class);`

2 - Then, at each case of your switch you implement this model:

```
case R.id.imageView1:
i.putExtra("url", "file:///android_asset/alocalpage.htm"); // use this to call a page on your assets folder
break;

case R.id.imageView2:
i.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.com");
break;
```

And so on, the same idea with the next imageViews, defining an url to each of them. That's all. Hope it helps. Best.

Comment: That's totally true, that's exactly what I want to do but I got really confused with how fragments work so I used activities instead.. Can you show me how I can do all of that with code please?

Comment: i'll try that tomorrow and come back to you, it's real late here, I barely focus. Good night

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused again.. fr_webview() is a costume `Fragment` class that contains my webview, right? Also what is the type of `fragments` and `titles`

Comment: I am really sorry, didn't explained what was that "fr_webview" in my code. This is the name of the java class I used in my app, from where I copied this snippet. Change the fr_webview to the name of the class you defined to be the class that holds your fragment (its a simpler one, because, at minimum, this class' work is just to load a xml layout with the webview inside).

Comment: okay, i figured that out but i dont know what to write exactly, how to load the xml layout within a class that extends `Fragment` i tried setContentView and it didn't work..

Comment: Sorry all the delay, got a good investigation on the case and choose the best option for you, in my opinion. Edited my whole answer. Best.

Comment: This is perfect, using Activities! It'll do for now, I'll learn about Fragments later.. Thank you so much!!